# Compile and run with javac and java using classpath classes in jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, javac, executable-jar

I'm trying to run a simple code in java by command prompt.
I have a jar.java file containing this :

```
public class jar{

public void print()
{
System.out.println("Jar success accesing !");
}}
```

and also i have a main.java that call use jar class:

```
public class main{

public static void main (String args[]){
jar jar1 = new jar();
jar1.print();
}}
```

I just tried to compile jar.java and then make it an jar archive, and then compile main class using this jar like here :

```
>javac jar.java
>jar cvf JAR.jar jar.class
>javac -cp JAR.jar main.java
```

Now, until here all works fine bun when i want to run main it doesn't work:

```
>java -cp JAR.jar main
```

and i get this :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.class
```

Where i am wrong ?

Comment: what is the package of these two classes? (maybe default, that is, they have no package?)

Comment: JAR.jar just has jar.class not the main.class. See your jar command. When you just have two classes, you shouldn't get this confused :) By the way follow java naming convention.

Comment: you are so far ! of course i have just jar.class inside, this class i want to call from an external main class. the same files are in the same package

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
java  main
```

You don't need **-cp** because you put all files in the same folder.
Your code don't work because you override the default value of **-cp** (current directory). Your **-cp** point only to JAR.jar.

Similar solutions:

```
java -cp 'main.class;JAR.jar' main
java -cp '.;JAR.jar' main
```