# How to compile and run a runnable JAR using only javac and jar

Tags: java, jar, java-11, javac

How can I compile and run a runnable JAR file using only `javac` and `jar`? I don't want to build the JAR file with an IDE or with tools like Gradle, Maven, or Ant, because I want to understand, for my own edification, how I can compile a runnable JAR using only `javac` and `jar`, and then how to correctly run this JAR with `java`.

I have tried building the JAR like this:

```
$ javac Example.java
$ file Example.class
Example.class: compiled Java class data, version 55.0
$ jar cvf Example.jar Example.class
added manifest
adding: Example.class(in = 682) (out= 456)(deflated 33%)
$ file Example.jar
Example.jar: Java archive data (JAR)
```

Then I tried various ways to execute the JAR, but none of them worked:

```
$ java -jar Example.jar main
no main manifest attribute, in Example.jar
$ java -cp '.;Example.jar' main
Error: Could not find or load main class main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
$ java -cp '.;Example.jar' Example
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
$ java -cp '.;Example.jar' -jar Example.jar Example
no main manifest attribute, in Example.jar
$ java -cp '.;Example.jar' -jar Example.jar main
no main manifest attribute, in Example.jar
```

My code, just to show I have an `Example` class and a `main()` function:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    private static class A {
        public int x = 7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        A a = new A();
        list.add(a);
        a.x = 5;
        System.out.println(a.x);
        System.out.println(list.get(0).x);
    }
}
```

My `javac`, `jar`, and `java` tools are all version 11.0.15.

I tried looking at the answers on [Compile and run with javac and java using classpath classes in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806379/compile-and-run-with-javac-and-java-using-classpath-classes-in-jar) and [javac compiles files and jars but java fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174215/javac-compiles-files-and-jars-but-java-fails), but none of the suggestions in the answers to these two questions worked for me.

Comment: A `runable` jar should already be compiled

Comment: 2 mistakes here: you forgot to add the `A` class (compiled to `Example$A.class`) to the jar file, use `jar cvf Example.jar *.class` to include both classes. b) `java -cp .\Example.jar Example` works for me. `java -cp ".;Example.jar" Example` also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @f1sh and @pdem, I found an answer:

```bash
$ javac Example.java
$ jar cfe Example.jar Example Example.class 'Example$A.class'
$ java -jar Example.jar
5
5
```

Is @f1sh points out in there comment, I needed to (A) include the `Example$A.class` class when creating the JAR, and (B) run the `java` command with the correct arguments.

As for making the JAR executable, a manifest file is required. A manifest file can be created manually, or you can let `jar` create it for you with the `e` option. The general format for using the `e` option is

```
java cfe <name of jar> <name of main class> <list of .class files>
```

For more info on using the `e` option or writing a manifest file by hand, see [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) or one of the other child pages of [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Comment: You also need a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file to be able to run with `java -jar yourfile.jar` That"s the definition of "executable jar". You main specify the main-class, the classpath.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066063/how-to-read-manifest-mf-file-from-jar-using-bash

Answer (score 0):

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ javac Example.java 
goose@t410:/tmp$ jar cvfe example.jar Example Example*.class 
added manifest
adding: Example$A.class(in = 293) (out= 233)(deflated 20%)
adding: Example.class(in = 682) (out= 457)(deflated 32%)
goose@t410:/tmp$ java -jar example.jar 
5
5
```

Note the penultimate argument to `jar` is the name of the main class

Comment: Apologies for being overly pedantic, but technically the name of the main class isn't the second last/penultimate argument to `jar`, since technically `Example*.class` is expanded by the shell to `Example.class 'Example$A.class'`. For more info on shell expansion for files the GNU bash shell, see [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

Comment: Hehe. OK let's call it the 'third token' then. Note I didn't call it the third argument ;)